# Default nano permissions in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I'm very new to learning bash, so I installed Cygwin so I don't have to go too in-depth with it to start. I also installed nano, but when I write anything through nano, it always saves with rw-r--r-- permissions, so I obviously can't run them. Can I change this without having to go into Windows explorer and manually change the permissions for every single file?

I know I can use a text editor to make files to run, but this is bothering me. Any answers I find online say to use the chmod command, but since this is in Cygwin, I can't.

I made a folder in my C:/ just for cygwin, and all the documents are in the home/me folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Explorer would be a bad choice, because we are talking about Cygwin permissions, not Windows permissions. If you want a script to have execute permission, you have to do a

```
chmod +x FILENAME
```

Most text editors don't do this automatically, because the editor can not know whether you want the x-bit to be set. You could write a script which on purpose has no x-rights (because you don't want to provide a #! line, and/or because the script is supposed to be included/sourced, and not executed standalone), or you just edit some text, which is not even intended to be a script, but for instance a CSV-file or a makefile.

I admit that it would be nice, if `nano` would ask you on saving a file which starts with a `#!`, whether you want to have the x-bit set,  and I suggest that you post this as [feature request](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=nano).

Comment: I can't use chmod, because I'm using Cygwin, chmod and su and similar commands don't work.

Comment: I actually tried using chmod and it worked, even though the FAQ of cygwin itself says chmod doesn't work... not sure I understand but at least it worked! Thanks

Comment: @Jenna: It depends on what you want to achieve. `chmod` affects the Cygwin permissions of a file. This means that if you type in a Cygwin shell (bash, zsh, ...) a command `C`, this command is searched in the PATH, and only  files with the execute bit are considered. So as long you stay in the Cygwin world, it should basically work. Don't forget that from the Windows viewpoint, you have a different model of handling permissions, and this can not be handled by `chmod`. See also [this](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/forcing-cygwin-to-create-sane-permissions-on-windows) discussion.